# Adding values to sequentially spaced list in python?

Tags: python, list, range

I am fairly new to Python and am confused how to represent the following code from Matlab into Python:

```
P = [2:35,50,100,200]
```

In Matlab, this will spit out: P = [2,3,...,35,50,100,200] ; however, I can't seem to figure out how to easily add values to an a list with sequential numbering as is easily done in Matlab. Any suggestions would be great. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried adding a value and then sorting the list so it retains its sequential numbering? - I am not familiar with matlab

Comment: @FujiApple except you can't - as the integers aren't iterable so it'll fail...

Comment: @JonClements indeed, how silly of me

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vanilla python doesn't have a dedicated syntax for this ... If you're working with lists, you need 2 steps:

```
lst = list(range(2, 36))  # for python2.x, you don't need `list(...)`
lst.extend([50, 100, 200])
```

If you have the "bleeding edge" (python3.5), [you *can* use unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/):

```
lst = [*range(2, 36), 50, 100, 200]
```

If you're using `numpy`, you can use the `r_` index trick (which looks somewhat similar to the matlab version):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.r_[2:36, 100, 200, 500]
array([  2,   3,   4,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,
    15,  16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,
    28,  29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35, 100, 200, 500])
```

Comment: @JonClements -- Thanks.  I suppose it _does_ have a syntax for that (sort of) :-)

Comment: `np.r_[2:36, 50, 100, 200]`?

Comment: @DSM -- I _thought_ there might be something in there.  I'll update.

Comment: `range(2, 36)` is a list. I guess you dont have to do a `list(range(2, 36))`

Comment: @Trying2Learn: `range` only returns a list in Python 2.  In modern Python it returns a special `range` object.

Comment: @DSM Oh yes. I checked. It returns a range object. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If you're fortunate enough to use Python 3.5, you can use [*additional unpacking generalizations*](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448) (from [PEP 448](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0448/)) with `range`:

```
>>> [*range(2, 36), 50, 100, 200]
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21 
 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 50, 100, 200]
```

Note that the last value generated by `range` is one less than the `end` argument.